# calculating and adding column values in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table

```
AffID    l      Commision
-------------------------
MW001              5

MW004              10

MW001              25

MW001              5

MW004              5
```

I want to submit a query that counts the amount in a column. So for example the output i am looking for is :

MW001 - 35

The query i am using now does not working correctly, it counts the actual amount of records.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM toutcome WHERE affID = '" . $_SESSION['affID'] . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo  $row['c'] ;
```

Comment: perhaps the name of the function should clue you in: COUNT() is doing exactly what you're getting. Perhaps you should use SUM() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to see all of the different commissions you can sum and group by

```
SELECT SUM(commission) FROM toutcome GROUP BY affID
```

so see a specific one just do this

```
SELECT SUM(commission) FROM toutcome WHERE affID = whicheveroneyouwant
```

Comment: $sql = "SELECT SUM(AffCommission) FROM toutcome WHERE affID = '" . $_SESSION['affID'] . "' and DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo  $row['AffCommission'] ;

Comment: @user3485335 do you have a date created in your table?

Comment: @user3485335 sure thing! don't forget to mark an answer as accepted to keep the community as is :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
select sum(Commission) from toutcome where affID = 'MW001'
```

So your query should be

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(Commission) as c FROM toutcome WHERE affID = '" . $_SESSION['affID'] . "'";
```